# Comparsion of min and max numbers between 2 group of columns

Tags: oracle

```
id  pointA1   pointA2  pointA3  pointB1  pointB2  pointB3

1   12.2      10       11.1     2.2      3.03     9  
2   102.2     10       -11.1    2.2      102.2    9
3   102.2     10       -11.1    -2.2     101.2    0
4   102.2     15       999      4        14       0.2
```

I have "season" table with this data, there is two type/group of columns "A" and "B" (3 from each type, in this sample data).

What I need: if any value from "A" type columns, exceeds any value from "B" type columns, get "1" for this row in new "result_column".

Example: for id = 1 and id = 4 rows, we must get this value, becuase any value, even most minimal from "pointA1,   pointA2,  pointA3" exceeds any most higher value from "pointB1,  pointB2  pointB3"

result should be

```
id  pointA1   pointA2  pointA3  pointB1  pointB2  pointB3 result_column

1   12.2      10       11.1     2.2      3.03     9       1
2   102.2     10       -11.1    2.2      102.2    9
3   102.2     10       -11.1    -2.2     101.2    0
4   102.2     15       999      4        14       0.2     1
```

Tried with min and max functions, but I'm in stuck...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
   ...
   case when least(a1, a2, a3) > greatest(b1, b2, b3) then 1 end as result_column
from ...
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    select season.* ,   
    CASE WHEN 
        least(pointA1, pointA2, pointA3) >  greatest(pointB1, pointB2, pointB3) then 1
    END AS result_column
    from season
    order by id
```

Comment: Happy to help @Oto Shavadze